# How can spirocerca lupi worms be killed in a dog?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

Anyone know if there is a cure for an infection of [spiorocerca lupi](http://www.merckvetmanual.com/mvm/digestive_system/gastrointestinal_parasites_of_small_animals/spirocerca_lupi_in_small_animals.html) (a specific worm found in southern US as well as subtropical areas of the world) in dogs or if there is any work towards finding a cure in the near future?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't really explain it any better than the info provided. The article stems from south africa which has a climate ideally suited the high amount of dogs with spirocerca lupi. Due to the common nature of it over here. Vets have successfully tried an injection based medicine called doramectin and in preventative scenarios milbemax to help the dogs.

Obviously if the illness has reached a late stage, it is very difficult to cure.

On the positive side, I was told by my vet that milebmax should be given to the dog every 6 months and doramectin once a year with the annual rabies, dewormer shots. This should be done to all dogs irrespective of whether it has the illness or not. Spirocerca has become so common that the medication should really be a must for any dog in my opinion. I have lost a dog from this so I speak from experience here(www.dhameergovind.co.za).

The major problem is that not all countries has such a big outbreak so naturally better medical results take longer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.news24.com/SouthAfrica/Local/Hillcrest-Fever/we-have-parasites-on-the-back-foot-for-now-take-advantage-dr-anthony-zambelli-20160229

Prevention injections on a yearly basis is the best thing to do.

Comment: Could you update your answer with the key information from the link?

Comment: I second that. Please add more information. Redirecting the OP to another website without presenting key information is exactly what we'd like to refrain from doing.

Comment: unfortunately the stack exchange editor is just a nightmare to work with in countries which have slow internet connections so redirecting helpful info is what is allowed according to stack exchange dev portal.